# Django with mongo and mysql where each database for different data

Tags: python, mysql, django, mongodb

I want to use Django with mongo and Mysql. In mongo I wanna store large data. In mysql I store tables for registration (Users, Countries, etc).

Follow my questions:
Can I use Django without forks for stroing data in non-relational databases ?
Can I use Different databases for different data ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/) to access mongodb from you regular django project.

But, you will operate with simple dicts, not with django models. You can [serialize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json) django model to json and store this json to mongo. And of course you can deserialize back from json to django model. But, you'll have to do it by yourself.

If you'll use django fork with mongodb support, then you still have to do many things by yourself, as most of django packages are working with django SQL ORM.